# Not getting StrongSwan IPsec to run: received netlink error: Network is unreachable / unable to install source route for [...]. Getting nuts already

Tags: ubuntu, configuration, ipsec, strongswan

I am trying to set up an ipsec tunnel with strongswan, used some tutorials for that and all went so far but there is no actually communication going trough the tunnel. The tunnel is established, but there is nothing transfered between the two machines. Prior of saying the tunnel is established, there is this error message:

```
received netlink error: Network is unreachable (101)
unable to install source route for 172.16.50.1
```

After this error it says:

```
CHILD_SA thevpn{9} established with SPIs c7c22d4e_i ce2c5536_o and TS 172.16.50.0/24 === 192.168.220.0/24
connection 'thevpn' established successfully
```

My Setup (both Ubuntu 22.04 LTS)

**Server A**
IP: 167.235.x.x
PrivateIP: 172.16.50.1

**Server B**
IP: 138.201.x.x
PrivateIP: 192.168.220.1

**Configuration on Server A (/etc/ipsec.conf) :**

```
config setup
    charondebug="ike 1, knl 1, cfg 0"
    uniqueids=no
conn thevpn
        type=tunnel
        auto=start
        keyexchange=ikev2
        authby=secret
        left=167.235.x.x
        leftsourceip=172.16.50.1
        leftsubnet=172.16.50.0/24
        right=138.201.x.x
        rightsubnet=192.168.220.0/24
        ike=3des-md5-modp2048!
        esp=3des-md5-modp2048!
        aggressive=no
        keyingtries=%forever
        ikelifetime=28800s
        lifetime=3600s
        dpddelay=15s
        dpdtimeout=20s
        dpdaction=restart
```

**Configuration on Server B (/etc/ipsec.conf) :**

```
config setup
        charondebug="ike 1, knl 1, cfg 0"
        uniqueids=no
conn thevpn2
        type=tunnel
        auto=start
        keyexchange=ikev2
        authby=secret
        right=167.235.x.x
        rightsubnet=172.16.50.0/24
        leftsourceip=192.168.220.1/24
        left=138.201.x.x
        leftsubnet=192.168.220.0/24
        ike=3des-md5-modp2048!
        esp=3des-md5-modp2048!
        aggressive=no
        keyingtries=%forever
        ikelifetime=28800s
        lifetime=3600s
        dpddelay=15s
        dpdtimeout=20s
        dpdaction=restart
```

And when I bring up the connection on Server B, this happens:

```
stablishing CHILD_SA anode6{3}
generating CREATE_CHILD_SA request 3 [ SA No KE TSi TSr ]
sending packet: from 138.201.x.x[4500] to 167.235.x.x[4500] (452 bytes)
received packet: from 167.235.x.x[4500] to 138.201.x.x[4500] (452 bytes)
parsed CREATE_CHILD_SA response 3 [ SA No KE TSi TSr ]
selected proposal: ESP:3DES_CBC/HMAC_MD5_96/MODP_2048/NO_EXT_SEQ
**received netlink error: Network is unreachable (101)
unable to install source route for 192.168.220.1**
CHILD_SA anode6{3} established with SPIs c5d3467d_i ca5f85dc_o and TS 192.168.220.0/24 === 172.16.50.0/24
connection 'thevpn2' established successfully
```

It's analogous on Server A, same error, just different local IP (the 172.16.50.1 one)
Nothing is established successfully. A PING to 172.16.50.1 returns nothing but vast emptiness..
The error you see in the log above and which I've copied here again is the same on Server A or Server B (just with different private IPs)

```
received netlink error: Network is unreachable (101)
unable to install source route for 192.168.220.1
```

I have configured my network on each server in a seperate file in **/etc/netplan/50-my-network.yaml**, this is the content of it:

```
network:
  version: 2
  ethernets:
    enp0s31f6:  
      addresses:
        - 192.168.220.1/24:  
            label: enp0s31f6:ipsec
      dhcp4: no
      dhcp6: no
```

Using PING on Server B for 192.168.220.1 works just fine. (Same on Server A for 172.16.50.1).. I just don't have any clue (ok the clue here is that the route doesn't get installed, but why I don't know). Why this is not working and why it gives the exact same error on two different machines.

My guess is, that the way I am installing the local IPs in netplan is somehow wrong? But why should it? It's pingable, services like NGINX can bind to that configured local IP (172.16.50.1) and also responsing correctly with serving a different website than when called with the external IP.

Does anybody have any clue? Thanks!

**Edit:1**

Changed netplan config to:

```
  network:
  version: 2
  ethernets:
    enp0s31f6:  
      addresses:
        - 192.168.220.1/24:  
            label: enp0s31f6:ipsec
      routes:
        - on-link: false
          from: 192.168.220.0/24
          to: 172.16.50.0/24
          
      dhcp4: no
      dhcp6: no
```

but nothing changed. Still no luck.

**Edit 2**
This is the main netplan config **/etc/netplan/01-netcfg.yaml**

```
network:
  version: 2
  renderer: networkd
  ethernets:
    enp41s0:
      addresses:
        - 138.201.x.x/32
      routes:
        - on-link: true
          to: 0.0.0.0/0
          via: 138.201.x.y
        - to: default
          via: ipv6-address::1
      nameservers:
        addresses:
          - w.x.y.z
          - ipv6.x.y.z::add:2
          - w.x.y.z2
          - ipv6.x.y.z::add:1
```

**Edit 3**

After changing netplan to

```
network:
  version: 2
  ethernets:
    enp41s0:   # use the name of your current network interface here
      addresses:
        - 172.16.50.1/24  # replace with your desired private IP address and subnet mask
      dhcp4: no
      dhcp6: no
```

and changing ipsec.conf to

```
.
.
        leftsourceip=172.16.50.1
        leftsubnet=172.16.50.1/32
.
.
```

still the same error:

```
.
.
selected proposal: ESP:3DES_CBC/HMAC_MD5_96/NO_EXT_SEQ
received netlink error: Network is unreachable (101)
unable to install source route for 172.16.50.1
CHILD_SA thevpn{2} established with SPIs c806e3a0_i 131c38e0_o and TS 172.16.50.1/32 === 192.168.220.0/24
connection 'actiovita-vpn' established successfully
```

**Edit 4**

The rule list:

```
0:  from all lookup local
220:    from all lookup 220
32766:  from all lookup main
32767:  from all lookup default
```

and the other command:

```
@ip route show table 220
@
```

no output there at all.

**Edit 5**

I have installed **Rocky Linux** instead of **Ubuntu 22.04 LTS** and it works there without problems. Setting up the private ip with `nmtui`seems to correctly install the private IP address along with the public IP address. So I strongly assume that the configuration of the network stack on Ubuntu (which I basically prefer to use) seems to be broken. Don't think at all that it's a strongswan problem anymore at all.

Comment: What kind of systems are you running that your VPN uses 3DES?!

Comment: Can you clarify what IP and PrivateIP mean in your question? IP seems to be your post-NAT public IP while your PrivateIP your local LAN IP. Or are these two publicly exposed servers with no private LAN?

Comment: The 3DES is a requirement of a client, I wouldn't use that at all.

Comment: @Ginnungagap There is no NAT running, For Server A IP 167.235.x.x is a public IP of the network interface, 172.16.50.1 is the private IP which is configured on the same network interface.

Comment: Can you add the output of `ip rule list` and `ip route show table 220` (both with the VPN mounted) to the question?

Comment: @Ginnungagap included your request to Edit 4. No output in the second command. What does it actually mean?

Answer (score 0):

I think that the source IP address for the left and right connections is not configured correctly. Make sure that the IP addresses specified in your ipsec.conf files match the IP addresses assigned to the respective interfaces in your netplan configuration files

edit after your edits:

Lets try to fix the routing setup on both server and then make a change in `StrongSwan` conf file

First update Server A in `/etc/netplan/50-my-network.yaml`

```
network:
  version: 2
  ethernets:
    enp0s31f6:
      addresses:
        - 172.16.50.1/24
      dhcp4: no
      dhcp6: no
```

then server B

```
network:
  version: 2
  ethernets:
    enp0s31f6:
      addresses:
        - 192.168.220.1/24
      dhcp4: no
      dhcp6: no
```

we apply `sudo netplan apply` then we update `StrongSwan`

for server A `/etc/ipsec.conf`

```
...
conn thevpn
    ...
    leftsourceip=172.16.50.1
    leftsubnet=172.16.50.1/32
    ...
```

then server B

```
...
conn thevpn2
    ...
    leftsourceip=192.168.220.1
    leftsubnet=192.168.220.1/32
    ...
```

lets restart `strongswan` `sudo systemctl restart strongswan`

check and it should work `sudo ipsec status`

Comment: Thank you for your answer, the IPs are correctly configured. In edit2 you can see the configuration of the primary netplan config for the public IP address

Comment: You welcome :)) I updated my post with your new informations

Comment: Just tried what you suggested, changing netplan and and reducing the strongswan config from /24 to /32 but still the error (edit 3)